# Porting Solutions from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2013, porting, visual-studio-2017

Has anybody experiences on porting from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2017? Or are there some documents? I've only found documents on porting from 2013 to 2015.

Greetings Noran

Comment: what kind of errors do you have when you open the project? or are you looking documents without event trying to see if there are any issues?

Comment: At our Company we think about to buy VS 2015 or 2017 and it would be nice to have an idea which workloads will occur.

Comment: @Norad: hard to tell - it depends on the type of the projects, how many you've got and the connections between them. I can give you an estimate from 0 to +Inf... just give this task 2h and try and see. If it blows with hundreds of errors to you it clear indication that it might not be an easy task. If zero or small number occurs it might be a day task..

Comment: You can try the trial version of both Visual Studios, and then try opening the old solution to see how much needs to be fixed. Usually the process is straightforward and the conversion succeeds, but it depends on the size of the solution obviously.

Comment: get the latest VS2017 RC and try to load your solution and look if you have issues or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Porting some Projects, i can tell it's no problem. No fixes were needed.